# Making my code shine and pro: Python in Azure Function Retrieveing the Data From Rest API

Tags: python, rest, azure

The code retrieves the data from PBI API - it's my first one and I would like to learn how to make it pro.
Here is the list of my questions:

1. Can you please analyze 2 functions: GetReports  and GetReportsUsers in accordance with the best practices? Should a table with metadata be added? Should a function responsible for creating the queries to API be written?
2. How the mechanism of logging/troubleshooting should be implemented?
3. Is the retry syntax correct?
4. Any other suggestions?

And here is the code:

````
import azure.functions as func
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import io
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import logging
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient



credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url='https://af-pbimonitoring.vault.azure.net', credential=credential)
api_client_secret = secret_client.get_secret('powerbi-api-admin').value
api_client_id = secret_client.get_secret('powerbi-api-admin-client-id').value
azure_tenant_id = secret_client.get_secret('azure-tenant-id').value
storage_key = secret_client.get_secret('api-storage-data').value
token_endpoint = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{azure_tenant_id}/oauth2/token'
resource = "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api"
account_name = "afstorageapidata"

def ListGroupUsers(name, id, UserAccessRight, group_id, table, processed_groups):
    # GraphAPI parameters
    resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com"

    # generate access token for Graph API
    body_graph = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": api_client_id,
        "client_secret": api_client_secret,
        "resource": resource
    }
    access_token_response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=body_graph)
    access_token_graph = access_token_response.json().get("access_token")
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token_graph}"
    }

    response = requests.get(f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group_id}/members", headers=headers)
    users_data = response.json()
    # add each group member to list
    for user in users_data['value']:
            user_type = 'Member'
            principal_type = 'User'
            if user["@odata.type"] == "#microsoft.graph.group":
                user_type = None
                principal_type = 'Group'
            else:
                principal_type = 'None'
            table.append({
                'id': id,
                'name': name,
                'identifier': user['id'],
                'UserAccessRight': UserAccessRight,
                'displayName': user['displayName'],
                'principalType': principal_type,
                'emailAddress': user['mail'],
                'graphId': user['id'],
                'userType': user_type,
                'requestDate' : datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            })
            # if member is a group and it haven't been listed already use recursion to list group members
            if user.get('@odata.type') == "#microsoft.graph.group" and user['id'] not in processed_groups:
                processed_groups.append(user['id'])
                return (ListGroupUsers(name, id, UserAccessRight, user['id'], table, processed_groups))

    return table


app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
@app.route(route="GetReportUsers")

def GetReportUsers(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    logging.info('HTTP trigger function started. Invoking Power BI API..,')

    body = req.get_body()
    json_data = json.loads(body.decode('utf-8'))


    # generate access token for Power BI API
    body_admin = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": api_client_id,
        "client_secret": api_client_secret,
        "resource": resource
    }
    access_token_response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=body_admin)
    access_token_admin = access_token_response.json().get("access_token")

    data = []

    # for each report 
    for item in json_data["value"]:
        try:
            report_name = item["reportName"]
            report_id = item["reportId"]

            # list report users
            api_url = f"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/reports/{report_id}/users"
            headers = {
                "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token_admin}"
            }
            response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)

            if response.status_code == 200:
                users_data = response.json()
                for user in users_data['value']:
                    data.append({
                        'id': report_id,
                        'name': report_name,
                        'identifier': user['identifier'],
                        'UserAccessRight': user['reportUserAccessRight'],
                        'displayName': user['displayName'],
                        'principalType': user['principalType'],
                        'emailAddress': user['identifier'],
                        'graphId': user['graphId'],
                        'userType': user.get('userType')
                    })
                    # use function to list group members
                    if user["principalType"] == "Group":
                        data += ListGroupUsers(report_name, report_id, user['reportUserAccessRight'], user["identifier"], [], [user['graphId']])
        except:
            logging.info(f"Report {item} didn't process successfully")

    logging.info("Data generated successfully. Starting connection to blob storage...")          
    # blob storage parameters
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['requestDate'] = today
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


    container_name = "staging"
    blob_path = f"reportusers/{today}/reportusers.csv"

    # connect to blob
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net", credential=storage_key)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_path)

    # save dataframe to csv
    csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)
    csv_bytes = csv_data.encode("utf-8")

    # upload file to blob
    with io.BytesIO(csv_bytes) as upload:
        blob_client.upload_blob(upload, overwrite=True)

    return func.HttpResponse(f"{data}")



@app.route(route="GetBearerToken")
def GetBearerToken(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    # generate access token for Power BI API
    body_admin = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": api_client_id,
        "client_secret": api_client_secret,
        "resource": resource
    }
    access_token_response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=body_admin)
    access_token_admin = access_token_response.json().get("access_token")


    return func.HttpResponse(f'{{ "access_token": "{access_token_admin}" }}', mimetype="application/json")



@app.route(route="GetReports", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def GetReports(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')


    body_admin = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": api_client_id,
        "client_secret": api_client_secret,
        "resource": resource
    }
    access_token_response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=body_admin)
    access_token_admin = access_token_response.json().get("access_token")

    api_url = f"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/reports"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token_admin}"
    }
    response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
    reports_json = response.json()

    data = []
    for report in reports_json['value']:
        data.append({
            'id': report.get('id'),
            'reportType': report.get('reportType'),
            'name': report.get('name'),
            'webUrl': report.get('webUrl'),
            'embedUrl': report.get('embedUrl'),
            'datasetId': report.get('datasetId'),
            'createdDateTime': report.get('createdDateTime'),
            'modifiedDateTime': report.get('modifiedDateTime'),
            'modifiedBy': report.get('modifiedBy'),
            'createdBy': report.get('createdBy'),
            'users': report.get('users'),
            'subscriptions': report.get('subscriptions'),
            'workspaceId': report.get('workspaceId')
        })



    logging.info("Data generated successfully. Starting connection to blob storage...")          
    # blob storage parameters
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['requestDate'] = today
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


    
    container_name = "staging"
    blob_path = f"reports/{today}/reports.csv"

    # connect to blob
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net", credential=storage_key)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_path)

    # save dataframe to csv
    csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)
    csv_bytes = csv_data.encode("utf-8")

    # upload file to blob
    with io.BytesIO(csv_bytes) as upload:
        blob_client.upload_blob(upload, overwrite=True)

    return func.HttpResponse(f"{data}")






@app.route(route="GetApps", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def GetApps(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    body_admin = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": api_client_id,
        "client_secret": api_client_secret,
        "resource": resource
    }
    access_token_response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=body_admin)
    access_token_admin = access_token_response.json().get("access_token")

    api_url = f"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/apps?$top=1000"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token_admin}"
    }
    response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
    apps_json = response.json()

    data = []
    for app in apps_json['value']:
        data.append({
            'id': app.get('id'),
            'name': app.get('name'),
            'lastUpdate': app.get('lastUpdate'),
            'description': app.get('description'),
            'publishedBy': app.get('publishedBy'),
            'workspaceId': app.get('workspaceId'),
            'users': app.get('users')
        })



    logging.info("Data generated successfully. Starting connection to blob storage...")          
    # blob storage parameters
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['requestDate'] = today
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


    
    container_name = "staging"
    blob_path = f"apps/{today}/apps.csv"

    # connect to blob
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net", credential=storage_key)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_path)

    # save dataframe to csv
    csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)
    csv_bytes = csv_data.encode("utf-8")

    # upload file to blob
    with io.BytesIO(csv_bytes) as upload:
        blob_client.upload_blob(upload, overwrite=True)

    return func.HttpResponse(f"{data}")



@app.route(route="GetGroups", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def GetGroups(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    body_admin = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": api_client_id,
        "client_secret": api_client_secret,
        "resource": resource
    }
    access_token_response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=body_admin)
    access_token_admin = access_token_response.json().get("access_token")

    api_url = f"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/groups?$top=5000"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token_admin}"
    }
    response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
    groups_json = response.json()

    data = []
    for group in groups_json['value']:
        data.append({
            'id': group.get('id'),
            'isReadOnly': group.get('isReadOnly'),
            'isOnDedicatedCapacity': group.get('isOnDedicatedCapacity'),
            'capacityMigrationStatus': group.get('capacityMigrationStatus'),
            'type': group.get('type'),
            'state': group.get('state'),
            'hasWorkspaceLevelSettings': group.get('hasWorkspaceLevelSettings'),
            'name': group.get('name')
        })


    logging.info("Data generated successfully. Starting connection to blob storage...")          
    # blob storage parameters
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['requestDate'] = today
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    
    container_name = "staging"
    blob_path = f"groups/{today}/groups.csv"

    # connect to blob
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net", credential=storage_key)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_path)

    # save dataframe to csv
    csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)
    csv_bytes = csv_data.encode("utf-8")

    # upload file to blob
    with io.BytesIO(csv_bytes) as upload:
        blob_client.upload_blob(upload, overwrite=True)

    return func.HttpResponse(f"{data}")



@app.route(route="GetDatasets", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def GetDatasets(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')



    body_admin = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": api_client_id,
        "client_secret": api_client_secret,
        "resource": resource
    }
    access_token_response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=body_admin)
    access_token_admin = access_token_response.json().get("access_token")

    api_url = f"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/datasets"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token_admin}"
    }
    response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
    datasets_json = response.json()

    data = []
    for dataset in datasets_json['value']:
        data.append({
            'id': dataset.get('id'),
            'name': dataset.get('name'),
            'webUrl': dataset.get('webUrl'),
            'addRowsAPIEnabled': dataset.get('addRowsAPIEnabled'),
            'configuredBy': dataset.get('configuredBy'),
            'isRefreshable': dataset.get('isRefreshable'),
            'isEffectiveIdentityRequired': dataset.get('isEffectiveIdentityRequired'),
            'isEffectiveIdentityRolesRequired': dataset.get('isEffectiveIdentityRolesRequired'),
            'targetStorageMode': dataset.get('targetStorageMode'),
            'createdDate': dataset.get('createdDate'),
            'contentProviderType': dataset.get('contentProviderType'),
            'createReportEmbedURL': dataset.get('createReportEmbedURL'),
            'qnaEmbedURL': dataset.get('qnaEmbedURL'),
            'upstreamDatasets': dataset.get('upstreamDatasets'),
            'users': dataset.get('users'),
            'isInPlaceSharingEnabled': dataset.get('isInPlaceSharingEnabled'),
            'workspaceId': dataset.get('workspaceId'),
            'autoSyncReadOnlyReplicas': dataset.get('queryScaleOutSettings').get('autoSyncReadOnlyReplicas'),
            'maxReadOnlyReplicas': dataset.get('queryScaleOutSettings').get('maxReadOnlyReplicas')
        })


    logging.info("Data generated successfully. Starting connection to blob storage...")          
    # blob storage parameters
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['requestDate'] = today
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
      
    container_name = "staging"
    blob_path = f"datasets/{today}/datasets.csv"

    # connect to blob
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net", credential=storage_key)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_path)

    # save dataframe to csv
    csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)
    csv_bytes = csv_data.encode("utf-8")

    # upload file to blob
    with io.BytesIO(csv_bytes) as upload:
        blob_client.upload_blob(upload, overwrite=True)

    return func.HttpResponse(f"{data}")


@app.route(route="GetAppUsers", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def GetAppUsers(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    logging.info('HTTP trigger function started. Invoking Power BI API..,')

    body = req.get_body()
    json_data = json.loads(body.decode('utf-8'))

    # generate access token for Power BI API
    body_admin = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": api_client_id,
        "client_secret": api_client_secret,
        "resource": resource
    }
    access_token_response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=body_admin)
    access_token_admin = access_token_response.json().get("access_token")

    data = []

    # for each report 
    for item in json_data["value"]:
        try:
            app_name = item["name"]
            app_id = item["id"]
            # list report users
            api_url = f"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/apps/{app_id}/users"
            headers = {
                "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token_admin}"
            }
            response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)            

            if response.status_code == 200:
                users_data = response.json()
                for user in users_data['value']:
                    data.append({
                        'id': app_id,
                        'name': app_name,
                        'UserAccessRight': user.get('appUserAccessRight'),
                        'emailAddress': user.get('emailAddress'),
                        'displayName': user.get('displayName'),
                        'identifier': user.get('identifier'),
                        'graphId': user.get('graphId'),
                        'principalType': user.get('principalType'),
                        'userType': user.get('userType')
                    })
                    # use function to list group members
                    if user["principalType"] == "Group":
                        data += ListGroupUsers(app_name, app_id, user['appUserAccessRight'], user["identifier"], [], [user['graphId']])
        except:
            logging.info(f"App {item} didn't process successfully")

    logging.info("Data generated successfully. Starting connection to blob storage...")          
    # blob storage parameters
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['requestDate'] = today
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


    
    container_name = "staging"
    blob_path = f"appusers/{today}/appusers.csv"

    # connect to blob
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net", credential=storage_key)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_path)

    # save dataframe to csv
    csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)
    csv_bytes = csv_data.encode("utf-8")

    # upload file to blob
    with io.BytesIO(csv_bytes) as upload:
        blob_client.upload_blob(upload, overwrite=True)

    return func.HttpResponse(f"{data}")



@app.route(route="GetGroupsUsers", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def GetGroupsUsers(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    logging.info('HTTP trigger function started. Invoking Power BI API..,')

    body = req.get_body()
    json_data = json.loads(body.decode('utf-8'))

    # generate access token for Power BI API
    body_admin = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": api_client_id,
        "client_secret": api_client_secret,
        "resource": resource
    }
    access_token_response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=body_admin)
    access_token_admin = access_token_response.json().get("access_token")

    data = []

    # for each report 
    for item in json_data["value"]:
        logging.info(f'{item}')
        try:
            group_name = item["name"]
            group_id = item["id"]
            # list report users
            api_url = f"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/groups/{group_id}/users"
            headers = {
                "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token_admin}"
            }
            response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)            

            if response.status_code == 200:
                users_data = response.json()
                for user in users_data['value']:
                    data.append({
                        'id': group_id,
                        'name': group_name,
                        'UserAccessRight': user.get('groupUserAccessRight'),
                        'emailAddress': user.get('emailAddress'),
                        'displayName': user.get('displayName'),
                        'identifier': user.get('identifier'),
                        'graphId': user.get('graphId'),
                        'principalType': user.get('principalType'),
                        'userType': user.get('userType')
                    })
                    # use function to list group members
                    if user["principalType"] == "Group":
                        data += ListGroupUsers(group_name, group_id, user['groupUserAccessRight'], user["identifier"], [], [user['graphId']])
        except:
            logging.info(f"Group {item} didn't process successfully")

    logging.info("Data generated successfully. Starting connection to blob storage...")          
    # blob storage parameters
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['requestDate'] = today
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    container_name = "staging"
    blob_path = f"groupusers/{today}/groupusers.csv"

    # connect to blob
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net", credential=storage_key)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_path)

    # save dataframe to csv
    csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)
    csv_bytes = csv_data.encode("utf-8")

    # upload file to blob
    with io.BytesIO(csv_bytes) as upload:
        blob_client.upload_blob(upload, overwrite=True)

    return func.HttpResponse(f"{data}")



@app.route(route="GetGraphGroups", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def GetGraphGroups(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    logging.info('HTTP trigger function started. Invoking Power BI API..,')

    # Graph API parameters
    resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com"

    # generate access token for Graph API
    body_graph = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": api_client_id,
        "client_secret": api_client_secret,
        "resource": resource
    }
    access_token_response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=body_graph)
    access_token_graph = access_token_response.json().get("access_token")
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token_graph}"
    }

    response = requests.get(f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/?$select=id,displayName", headers=headers)
    groups_json = response.json()

    data = []
    for group in groups_json['value']:
        data.append({
        'id': group.get('id'),
        'displayName': group.get('displayName')
    })


    logging.info("Data generated successfully. Starting connection to blob storage...")          
    # blob storage parameters
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['requestDate'] = today
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    
    container_name = "staging"
    blob_path = f"graphgroups/{today}/graphgroups.csv"

    # connect to blob
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net", credential=storage_key)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_path)

    # save dataframe to csv
    csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)
    csv_bytes = csv_data.encode("utf-8")

    # upload file to blob
    with io.BytesIO(csv_bytes) as upload:
        blob_client.upload_blob(upload, overwrite=True)

    return func.HttpResponse(f"{data}")



@app.route(route="GetGraphUsers", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def GetGraphUsers(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    logging.info('HTTP trigger function started. Invoking Power BI API..,')

    resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com"

    # generate access token for Graph API
    body_graph = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": api_client_id,
        "client_secret": api_client_secret,
        "resource": resource
    }
    access_token_response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=body_graph)
    access_token_graph = access_token_response.json().get("access_token")
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token_graph}"
    }

    response = requests.get(f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,displayName,givenName,surname,mail,mailNickname,jobTitle,department,companyName,officeLocation,city,accountEnabled", headers=headers)
    users_json = response.json()

    data = []
    for user in users_json['value']:
        data.append({
            'id': user.get('id'),
            'displayName': user.get('displayName'),
            'givenName': user.get('givenName'),
            'surname': user.get('surname'),
            'mail': user.get('mail'),
            'mailNickname': user.get('mailNickname'),
            'jobTitle': user.get('jobTitle'),
            'department': user.get('department'),
            'companyName': user.get('companyName'),
            'officeLocation': user.get('officeLocation'),
            'city': user.get('city'),
            'accountEnabled': user.get('accountEnabled')
        })


    logging.info("Data generated successfully. Starting connection to blob storage...")          
    # blob storage parameters
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['requestDate'] = today
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
   
    container_name = "staging"
    blob_path = f"graphusers/{today}/graphusers.csv"

    # connect to blob
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net", credential=storage_key)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_path)

    # save dataframe to csv
    csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)
    csv_bytes = csv_data.encode("utf-8")

    # upload file to blob
    with io.BytesIO(csv_bytes) as upload:
        blob_client.upload_blob(upload, overwrite=True)

    return func.HttpResponse(f"{data}")



@app.route(route="GetGraphUsersAssignedPlans", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def GetGraphUsersAssignedPlans(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    logging.info('HTTP trigger function started. Invoking Power BI API..,')

    resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com"

    # generate access token for Graph API
    body_graph = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": api_client_id,
        "client_secret": api_client_secret,
        "resource": resource
    }
    access_token_response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=body_graph)
    access_token_graph = access_token_response.json().get("access_token")
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token_graph}"
    }

    response = requests.get(f"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,assignedPlans", headers=headers)
    users_json = response.json()

    data = []
    for user in users_json['value']:
        data.append({
                'id': user.get('id'),
                'items' : user.get('assignedPlans')
            })


    logging.info("Data generated successfully. Starting connection to blob storage...")          
    # blob storage parameters
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['requestDate'] = today
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
   
    container_name = "staging"
    blob_path = f"graphusersassignedplans/{today}/graphusersassignedplans.csv"

    # connect to blob
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net", credential=storage_key)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_path)

    # save dataframe to csv
    csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)
    csv_bytes = csv_data.encode("utf-8")

    # upload file to blob
    with io.BytesIO(csv_bytes) as upload:
        blob_client.upload_blob(upload, overwrite=True)

    return func.HttpResponse(f"{data}")




@app.route(route="GetGroupReports", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def GetGroupReports(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    logging.info('HTTP trigger function started. Invoking Power BI API..,')

    body = req.get_body()
    json_data = json.loads(body.decode('utf-8'))

    # generate access token for Power BI API
    body_admin = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": api_client_id,
        "client_secret": api_client_secret,
        "resource": resource
    }
    access_token_response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=body_admin)
    access_token_admin = access_token_response.json().get("access_token")

    data = []

    # for each report 
    for item in json_data["value"]:

        group_id = item["workspaceId"]
        group_name = item["workspaceName"]
        # list report users
        api_url = f'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/groups/{group_id}/reports'
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token_admin}"
        }
        response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)            

        groups_json = response.json()
        for report in groups_json['value']:
            data.append({
                'workspaceId' : group_id,
                'workspaceName' : group_name,
                'id': report.get('id'),
                'reportType': report.get('reportType'),
                'name': report.get('name'),
                'webUrl': report.get('webUrl'),
                'embedUrl': report.get('embedUrl'),
                'datasetId': report.get('datasetId'),
                'createdDateTime': report.get('createdDateTime'),
                'modifiedDateTime': report.get('modifiedDateTime'),
                'modifiedBy': report.get('modifiedBy'),
                'createdBy': report.get('createdBy'),
                'endorsement': report.get('endorsementDetails'),
                'users': report.get('users'),
                'subscriptions': report.get('subscriptions')
            })

    logging.info("Data generated successfully. Starting connection to blob storage...")          
    # blob storage parameters
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['requestDate'] = today
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


    container_name = "staging"
    blob_path = f"groupreports/{today}/groupreports.csv"

    # connect to blob
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net", credential=storage_key)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_path)

    # save dataframe to csv
    csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)
    csv_bytes = csv_data.encode("utf-8")

    # upload file to blob
    with io.BytesIO(csv_bytes) as upload:
        blob_client.upload_blob(upload, overwrite=True)

    return func.HttpResponse(f"{data}")


@app.route(route="GetAppReports", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def GetAppReports(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    logging.info('HTTP trigger function started. Invoking Power BI API..,')

    body = req.get_body()
    json_data = json.loads(body.decode('utf-8'))

    # generate access token for Power BI API
    body_admin = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": api_client_id,
        "client_secret": api_client_secret,
        "resource": resource
    }
    access_token_response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=body_admin)
    access_token_admin = access_token_response.json().get("access_token")

    data = []

    # for each report 
    for item in json_data["value"]:

        app_id = item["appId"]
        app_name = item["appName"]
        # list report users
        api_url = f'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/apps/{app_id}/reports'
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token_admin}"
        }
        response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)            

        apps_json = response.json()
        for report in apps_json['value']:
            data.append({
                'appId' : app_id,
                'appName' : app_name,
                'id': report.get('id'),
                'reportType': report.get('reportType'),
                'name': report.get('name'),
                'webUrl': report.get('webUrl'),
                'embedUrl': report.get('embedUrl'),
                'datasetId': report.get('datasetId'),
                'createdDateTime': report.get('createdDateTime'),
                'modifiedDateTime': report.get('modifiedDateTime'),
                'modifiedBy': report.get('modifiedBy'),
                'createdBy': report.get('createdBy'),
                'users': report.get('users'),
                'subscriptions': report.get('subscriptions'),
                'workspaceId': report.get('workspaceId')
            })

    logging.info("Data generated successfully. Starting connection to blob storage...")          
    # blob storage parameters
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['requestDate'] = today
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    container_name = "staging"
    blob_path = f"appreports/{today}/appreports.csv"

    # connect to blob
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net", credential=storage_key)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_path)

    # save dataframe to csv
    csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)
    csv_bytes = csv_data.encode("utf-8")

    # upload file to blob
    with io.BytesIO(csv_bytes) as upload:
        blob_client.upload_blob(upload, overwrite=True)

    return func.HttpResponse(f"{data}")




@app.route(route="GetActivityEvents", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def GetActivityEvents(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    logging.info('HTTP trigger function started. Invoking Power BI API..,')

    body = req.get_body()
    json_data = json.loads(body.decode('utf-8'))

    # generate access token for Power BI API
    body_admin = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": api_client_id,
        "client_secret": api_client_secret,
        "resource": resource
    }
    access_token_response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=body_admin)
    access_token_admin = access_token_response.json().get("access_token")

    data = []

    yesterday_start = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
    yesterday_end = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).replace(hour=23, minute=59, second=59, microsecond=0)
    # for each report 
    for item in json_data["value"]:

        activity_type = item["ActivityType"]
        # list report users
        api_url = f"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/activityevents?startDateTime='{yesterday_start.isoformat()}Z'&endDateTime='{yesterday_end.isoformat()}Z'&$filter=Activity eq '{activity_type}'"
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token_admin}"
        }
        response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)            

        activities_json = response.json()
        
        for activity in activities_json['activityEventEntities']:
            data.append({
                "Id": activity["Id"],
                "RecordType": activity["RecordType"],
                "CreationTime": activity["CreationTime"],
                "Operation": activity["Operation"],
                "OrganizationId": activity["OrganizationId"],
                "UserType": activity["UserType"],
                "UserKey": activity["UserKey"],
                "Workload": activity["Workload"],
                "UserId": activity["UserId"],
                "ClientIP": activity["ClientIP"],
                "Activity": activity["Activity"],
                "ItemName": activity.get("ItemName"),
                "WorkSpaceName": activity.get("WorkSpaceName"),
                "DatasetName": activity.get("DatasetName"),
                "ReportName": activity.get("ReportName"),
                "CapacityId": activity.get("CapacityId"),
                "CapacityName": activity.get("CapacityName"),
                "WorkspaceId": activity.get("WorkspaceId"),
                "ObjectId": activity.get("ObjectId"),
                "DatasetId": activity.get("DatasetId"),
                "ReportId": activity.get("ReportId"),
                "ArtifactId": activity.get("ArtifactId"),
                "ArtifactName": activity.get("ArtifactName"),
                "IsSuccess": activity["IsSuccess"],
                "ReportType": activity.get("ReportType"),
                "RequestId": activity["RequestId"],
                "ActivityId": activity["ActivityId"],
                "DistributionMethod": activity.get("DistributionMethod"),
                "ConsumptionMethod": activity.get("ConsumptionMethod"),
                "ArtifactKind": activity.get("ArtifactKind"),
                "RefreshEnforcementPolicy": activity.get("RefreshEnforcementPolicy")
            })

    logging.info("Data generated successfully. Starting connection to blob storage...")          
    # blob storage parameters
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['requestDate'] = today
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


    container_name = "staging"
    blob_path = f"activityevents/{today}/activityevents.csv"

    # connect to blob
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net", credential=storage_key)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_path)

    # save dataframe to csv
    csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)
    csv_bytes = csv_data.encode("utf-8")

    # upload file to blob
    with io.BytesIO(csv_bytes) as upload:
        blob_client.upload_blob(upload, overwrite=True)

    return func.HttpResponse(f"{data}")



@app.route(route="GetDatasources", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def GetDatasources(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    logging.info('HTTP trigger function started. Invoking Power BI API..,')

    body = req.get_body()
    json_data = json.loads(body.decode('utf-8'))

    # generate access token for Power BI API
    body_admin = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": api_client_id,
        "client_secret": api_client_secret,
        "resource": resource
    }
    access_token_response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=body_admin)
    access_token_admin = access_token_response.json().get("access_token")

    data = []

    # for each report 
    for item in json_data["value"]:

        dataset_id = item["datasetId"]
        # list report users
        api_url = f'https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/datasets/{dataset_id}/datasources'
        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token_admin}"
        }
        response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)            
        datasets_json = response.json()
        for datasource in datasets_json['value']:
            data.append({
                'datasetId' : dataset_id,
                'datasourceType': datasource.get('datasourceType'),
                'server': datasource['connectionDetails'].get('server'),
                'database': datasource['connectionDetails'].get('database'),
                'datasourceId': datasource.get('datasourceId'),
                'gatewayId': datasource.get('gatewayId')
            })

    logging.info("Data generated successfully. Starting connection to blob storage...")          
    # blob storage parameters
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['requestDate'] = today
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


    
    container_name = "staging"
    blob_path = f"datasources/{today}/datasources.csv"

    # connect to blob
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net", credential=storage_key)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_path)

    # save dataframe to csv
    csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)
    csv_bytes = csv_data.encode("utf-8")

    # upload file to blob
    with io.BytesIO(csv_bytes) as upload:
        blob_client.upload_blob(upload, overwrite=True)

    return func.HttpResponse(f"{data}")


@app.route(route="GetDatasetRefreshes", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.FUNCTION)
def GetDatasetRefreshes(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    body_admin = {
        "grant_type": "client_credentials",
        "client_id": api_client_id,
        "client_secret": api_client_secret,
        "resource": resource
    }
    access_token_response = requests.post(token_endpoint, data=body_admin)
    access_token_admin = access_token_response.json().get("access_token")

    api_url = f"https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/admin/capacities/refreshables?$top=5000"
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token_admin}"
    }
    response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)
    datasets_json = response.json()

    data = []

    for refreshable in datasets_json['value']:
        data.append({
            'id': refreshable.get('id'),
            'name': refreshable.get('name'),
            'kind': refreshable.get('kind'),
            'id': refreshable['lastRefresh'].get('id'),
            'refreshType': refreshable['lastRefresh'].get('refreshType'),
            'startTime': refreshable['lastRefresh'].get('startTime'),
            'endTime': refreshable['lastRefresh'].get('endTime'),
            'serviceExceptionJson': refreshable['lastRefresh'].get('serviceExceptionJson'),
            'status': refreshable['lastRefresh'].get('status'),
            'requestId': refreshable['lastRefresh'].get('requestId'),
            'extendedStatus': refreshable['lastRefresh'].get('extendedStatus'),
            'refreshAttempts': refreshable['lastRefresh'].get('refreshAttempts'),
            'days': refreshable['refreshSchedule'].get('days'),
            'times': refreshable['refreshSchedule'].get('times'),
            'enabled': refreshable['refreshSchedule'].get('enabled'),
            'localTimeZoneId': refreshable['refreshSchedule'].get('localTimeZoneId'),
            'notifyOption': refreshable['refreshSchedule'].get('notifyOption'),
            'configuredBy': refreshable.get('configuredBy')
        })



    logging.info("Data generated successfully. Starting connection to blob storage...")          
    # blob storage parameters
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['requestDate'] = today
    today = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


    
    container_name = "staging"
    blob_path = f"datasetrefreshes/{today}/datasetrefreshes.csv"

    # connect to blob
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url=f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net", credential=storage_key)
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob_path)

    # save dataframe to csv
    csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)
    csv_bytes = csv_data.encode("utf-8")

    # upload file to blob
    with io.BytesIO(csv_bytes) as upload:
        blob_client.upload_blob(upload, overwrite=True)

    return func.HttpResponse(f"{data}")
```
````

Comment: Did you implement the statement of the question 2 or not ?

Comment: to some extend yes - but I'm not sure it's good enough